vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR doesn't work STM32F4 disc board
I'm stuck when I try to use vTaskNotifyGiveFromISRin ISR on my STM32F4 DISC board, I use FreeRTOS Kernel V10.3.1.
First of all in my main.c I create two task, in main.c
TaskHandle_t handleRFInt;
static TaskHandle_t initTask;

   xTaskCreate((TaskFunction_t) T_initTask, "start_task", 1024,
                NULL, 0, (TaskHandle_t *) initTask);

   xTaskCreate((TaskFunction_t) T_handleRFInt, "start_task", 1024,
                NULL, 0, (TaskHandle_t *) handleRFInt);

   vTaskStartScheduler();

T_ initTaskinit some pin and like PB9 with extern interrupt
....
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
....

My interruptworks fine (because if I use my static s_newRf95Interrupt variable I'm able to detect each interrupt), so righ now i'd like to use vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR
So here is my HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callbackfunction :
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
  BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;

  if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_9) {
    s_newRf95Interrupt = 1;
    vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(handleRFInt ,&xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
  }
}

And in my second task I have this :
void T_handleRFInt(void const *argument) {
  static uint32_t thread_notification;

  while(1){
       thread_notification = ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 
                        portMAX_DELAY);

        if(thread_notification)
        {
            USER_LOG_INFO("here???");
        }
  }
}

I never see my log, what I missed?

you already have one UB in your code. vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(handleRFInt ,&xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);  you pass reference to the local variable. Also - do you clean IRQ pending flags?

Also try to loop in your log task.

I use notifications and they work very well.

How are initTask and handleRFInt defined? Are you getting compiler warnings around your task creation?

@0___________ Yes the interrupt is cleared in HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandlermy interrupt routine works weel beceause if I don't use vTaskNotifyGiveFromISReverything works. Should I init my pin and NVIC before creating task?

10124 as stack size is not looking good

@pmacfarlane no warning when I compile

@0___________ yes sorry typo issue

How are initTask and handleRFInt defined?  I strongly suspect you are using these wrongly.

@pmacfarlane in my main.c I have TaskHandle_t handleRFInt; and static TaskHandle_t initTask; after thaht I have xTaskCreatelike in my post. I've edited my post to add definition.

@simon 1) task should not return: https://www.freertos.org/implementing-a-FreeRTOS-task.html, your T_handleRFInt should be in loop or call vTaskDelete at end
2) is it possible you configure interrupt before T_handleRFInt is created?

@tymmej I'm in while(1)i was a post error, corrected. Yes I configure my interrupt before calling xTaskCreateand vTaskStartSchedulershould I create my interrupt after that ?

@simon You need to pass the address of your TaskHandle_t to xTaskCreate. (TaskHandle_t *) &initTask And in fact you don't even need the cast, since you will be passing the correct type anyway.

In addition to @pmacfarlane make handleRFInt also static or global if it’s currently main stack variable. Main stack is reset and used as interrupt stack by FreeRTOS on Cortex-M when starting the scheduler.
